# Entanglement fidelity for a single qubit?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

So I have been working out problems from the book "Quantum Computing Explained" by David McMahon. On page 166 he defines "Entanglement Fidelity" and says the following:
Consider a density operator for a single qubit that is diagonal with respect to the computational basis:
$\rho = f \vert 0\rangle\langle 0\vert+ (1-f)\vert 1\rangle\langle 1\vert$. The parameter $f$ is known as the entanglement fidelity. For example, if 
$\rho = (3/4) \vert 0\rangle\langle 0\vert+ (1/4)\vert 1\rangle\langle 1\vert$ ,then the entanglement fidelity is 3/4. 
I have a few questions regarding this:

A) What does entanglement fidelity mean? (especially in the case of a single qubit)

B) Since the trace of a density matrix should be 1, I understand that the parameter $f$ can range between 0 to 1. How should I interpret the various values of the parameter $f$?

Comment: Well, as I have mentioned in the question, I've only come across such a thing in the book by David McMahon called "Quantum computing explained" . Don't know of any other reference. I tried googling it, couldn't find anything.

Comment: As far as I can understand, this is not a correct definition for entanglement fidelity.  A system must have more than one particle (or at least more than one spin-half degree of freedom) for it to be possible to have entanglement. The parameter $f$ that you are describing is closer to something like 'state purity'. If $f$ is 0 or 1 then the state is pure; if $f = 1/2$ then the state is completely mixed.